Laravel AWS SES Issue after Upgrade to Laravel 11: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"
I have spun up a new EC2 and moved my Laravel site, domain (& DNS records) over to the new EC2. I've done this in order to upgrade to PHP 8.2, Laravel 11 & utilise Laravel Reverb, all of which is done & working. My only issue at the moment is emailing.
I have tried all of the usual solutions, re-generating SMTP credentials, re-creating IAM accounts and finally I have also settled on utilising an IAM Service Role which is directly linked to my EC2 so as to avoid storing credentials on the server.
I have double and triple checked that my domain identity is verified, there aren't even any AWS recommendations on the identity, previously it had issues with the MAIL FROM but I cleared those DNS records and verified them, now there's no recommendation.
ChatGPT 4/4o falls flat on this, it has also just run me through every different sequence of changing credentials and testing and the result is always this same error message.
Hoping someone has run into a similar situation that they were able to rectify.
Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\UnexpectedResponseException: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied". in /home/forge/(website)/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/SmtpTransport.php:333
I'm hoping there's a small flux capacitor switch that I forgot to toggle, thanks guys.

550 means blocked(?), possibly flagged as a spam thing? IP address doesn't show up on SpamCop.net.

Ok, so I wrote a small bash script to utilise my SMTP details and that worked fine. So it's definitely a Laravel related issue, not a configuration in SES issue.

I was able to send via Tinker, so that confirms my SES credentials are OK (probably were a long time ago) - but there's something peculiar here in relation to upgrading from Laravel 10 to 11 because my transactional emails are still failing with 550 every time, including when I retry queued jobs.

I have even deleted & re-verified the domain twice. I have tested both creating new email jobs and re-trying old ones. They all result in the same error 550 5.7.1 Relaying denied. Probably time to reach out to Amazon support.

Useful Tips for Debugging SES / Mail Issues
Some important things to take note of that may assist others who run into similar pitfalls before I pontificate upon the wherewithal required to set up SES and how my issue was resolved.

1.) Keep your DNS records simple and understand what is doing what, don't just copy and paste & leave it all to the Gods. To successfully set up a custom MAIL FROM domain with Amazon AWS SES, you must publish exactly one MX record to the DNS server of your MAIL FROM domain. If the MAIL FROM domain has multiple MX records, the custom MAIL FROM setup with Amazon SES will fail.


2.) Be sure to check all log files, there were warnings inside of my laravel log file that alluded to the true issue, whilst the logged error in the failed_jobs table only seemed to point to SES rejection.


3.) Be sure to check "base level" items whenever solving a problem; had I thrown my hands in the air a few hours ago and rebooted the server I would have discovered that I had solved my problem already - albeit without sound reasoning as to how I happened upon the solution.


4.) Always test, especially credentials, outside of the ecosystem you are having trouble in to be sure the credentials are correct. Confirming that the SMTP details were indeed working with a simple mail script made me commit my efforts to what was wrong with Laravel / my code itself.


So what was the problem?
So, in my particular case I had the right credentials very early on no matter how many times I re-generated / re-verified, the error message actually alludes to this 250/251/252 - this basically means auth handshake tick, username tick, password tick, but with a response of 550 "Blocked"
Real error message should be: auth accepted, your email format sucks.
Because the subject lines I generate had a malformed name in them, only due to my own logging inside of my mailable was I able to be alerted to this & rectify it.
One final important note:
! RESTART YOUR QUEUE/S !

After fixing things, there will be no indication of the solution having taken hold unless you restart the queue.
Hopefully this will help someone out there with this error message. Double & triple check your mailable formatting, see if it goes through fine to Mailgun or something like that and restart your queues after every mailable adjustment.
